# Данные из столбца построчно по признаку

Tags: excel, vba

Здравствуйте. Есть книга excel, где на одном листе есть данные о людях в одном столбце. Нужен макрос, который будет проверять ячейку на значение в столбце с данными и, если там число, то копировать эту ячейку и две следующие в этом столбце на другой лист в строку. Вот что у меня получилось путем гугления. Скрипт копирует всю строку той ячейки, где нашел число. 
Заранее спасибо.

```
Sub Test()
Dim iCell As Range, Priznak As Variant

For Each iCell In Range("A1", [A1].End(xlDown))
    If IsNumeric(iCell) Then
        With Sheets("Лист2") 
            iCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=.Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A")
        End With
    End If
Next iCell
End Sub
```

Comment: *копировать эту ячейку и две следующие в этом столбце* - не ошибка? Копировать ячейку и две ПОД ней? В  моем ответе копирование по строке. Уточните, если нужно, подправлю

Comment: Не менял, добавил в ответ второй вариант

Comment: Нужно копирование ячеек ПОД ней. Не по строке!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В показанном коде достаточно изменить строку внутри цикла на

```
 iCell.Resize(1, 3).Copy .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A").Resize(1, 3)
```

Но лучше работать с массивами, обращаясь к листу только для загрузки данных и выгрузки результата.

Проверяем данные в столбце *A*. Если там число, то копируем три ячейки этой строки (столбцов *A, B, C*). Заполненный массив выгружаем на другой лист, предварительно очистив его (если нужно) от старых данных.

```
Sub Test2()
Dim a()
Dim k As Long, i As Long
    With ActiveSheet ' можно заменить на другое название листа - Worksheets("Лист1")'
        k = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' последняя заполненная строка в столбце "A"'
        a = Range("A1").Resize(k, 3).Value ' данные в массив'
    End With

    k = 0 ' подготовка переменной для хранения счетчика записей'

    For i = 1 To UBound(a) ' цикл по записям в массиве'
        If a(i, 1) <> Empty Then ' если данные есть'
            If IsNumeric(a(i, 1)) Then
                k = k + 1 ' строка перезаписи в массив'
                a(k, 1) = a(i, 1) ' копируем данные'
                a(k, 2) = a(i, 2)
                a(k, 3) = a(i, 3)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    With Sheets("Лист2")
        ' если нужно, раскомментировать очистку листа'
'         .UsedRange.EntireRow.Delete ' чистим лист'
         .Range("A1").Resize(k, 3).Value = a ' выгрузка из массива на лист'
    End With
End Sub
```

Если нужно копировать текущую ячейку и две ниже, достаточно немного изменить "внутренность" цикла:

```
    If IsNumeric(a(i, 1)) Then
        k = k + 1 ' строка перезаписи в массив'
        a(k, 1) = a(i, 1) ' копируем данные'
        a(k, 2) = a(i + 1, 1)
        a(k, 3) = a(i + 2, 1)
        i = i + 2
    End If
```

Comment: Я все так же получаю только числа в столбце. Расклад такой: в ячейке А1 - номер, в А2 - имя, в А3 - фамилия. Это записи об одной личности. Далее в А4 - номер другой персоны, в А5 - ее имя, в А6 - фамилия и т.д. после работы скрипта нужно, чтобы на втором листе были в первую строку записаны номер, имя и фамилия первой персоны, во вторую строку - второй и т.д.

Comment: Замените в основном коде строки в цикле строками, показанными ниже., и макрос будет извлекать в строку данные из трех ячеек одного столбца

Comment: Да, все отлично работает. Спасибо огромное